# How to pre populate charfield values, as a dropdown list from one model to another in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to pre populate charfield values, as a dropdown list from one model to another in admin panel?

In other words having the below two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

If I have let's say ten instances stored of model A with `name` field having  `null = False` , I want these values to show up as a dropdown list when I am trying to add a new instance of model B in admin panel at the `name` text field area.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not use a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I do not want a relationship like this, just the values. My models have to do with seo , so I want a to have the values (provided with custom migrations) in a MetaTag model (A) and more than one proxy models(B) taking these values

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than I've expected.

After the custom migration needed to prepopulate the `name` field value for model `A`, I had to create the function:

```
def get_names():
    results = A.objects.all()
    return ((result.name,result.name) for result in results)
```

and change in `B` model accordingly the `name` value for receiving a dynamic tuple from the above function.

```
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=get_names(), null=True, blank=True)
```